# WPF designer not showing anymore

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a very strange problem with my Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installation on a 64 bit system.
When I double click a xaml file in the solution explorer, nothing happens. The Designer doesn't show. However, when I CTRL + Tab, the file appears in the "Active Files" list.
Anyone has encountered this before? Is this a know bug? I couldn't find anything on the net...

Comment: Do you mean that only the XAML text editor is showing. Or that nothing is showing at all?

Comment: Have you tried to Reset Your Settings as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx?

Comment: @Meleak: Good idea, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to finish this question:
After some weeks it started working again. Never found out why or why it stopped working...

Answer (score 1):

I would check that the designer isnt simply being hidden away. Try (Menu) View > Designer or Shift+F7

Answer (score 1):

Right click the xaml file, select `Open With...`. Which is the default editor? It should be `Windows Presentation Foundation Designer`.

Comment: That's the default editor. Even choosing the WPF Designer as editor manually doesn't change the described behavior.